# Join three completed tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: tblFuel, tblDoXang, tblDrivingTime2. Now I want to show the fuelLevel field in tblFuel that satisfy some condition in tblDrivingTime2 and if in specific of time(base on timestamp in tblFuel) if I check there are adding fuel action in tblDoXang, I have to insert it(nhienLieu field in tblDoXang) to report that show fuelLevel above. The goal is likely:
tblFuel:

```
timestamp     fuelLevel
123456         10
123467         8
123478         50
123489         20
```

tblDrivingTime2:

```
 stopTime     
    123456         
    123478         
    123489
```

this will print:

```
10
50
20
```

and now we check if
tblDoXang

```
thoiGian      nhienLieu
123457        15
123466        10
```

it will insert to result above and finally, the result will be:

```
10
15
10
50
20
```

I have written two separated queries to do these tasks:

```
SELECT distinct from_unixtime(F.timestamp), F.fuelLevel FROM gtse.tblFuel F 
INNER JOIN gtse.tblDrivingTime2 D 
ON D.accountID = F.accountID and D.deviceID = F.deviceID 
where (from_unixtime(F.timestamp) between '2014-10-10 10:52:02' and '2014-10-30 10:52:02')
and F.accountID = 'vinhnghia'
and F.deviceID = '14C-00263'
and (D.reportType = '2' or D.reportType = '3')
and F.timestamp = D.stopTime
order by F.timestamp asc;
```

this will print the result in the first time(10,50 and 20) and this:

```
SELECT distinct from_unixtime(D.thoiGian), D.nhienLieu
FROM gtse.tblDoXang D
inner join gtse.tblFuel F
on D.accountID = F.accountID and D.deviceID = F.deviceID
where D.accountID = 'vinhnghia' and D.deviceID = '14C-00263'
and D.thoiGian <= F.timestamp
order by D.thoiGian asc;
```

will show the value(15,10). And my question is how to join two queries to show the final result?:

```
10
15
10
50
20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try with the UNION clause:

```
( 
    SELECT distinct 
       from_unixtime(F.timestamp) As col_1, 
       F.fuelLevel as col_2
    FROM 
       gtse.tblFuel F 
       INNER JOIN gtse.tblDrivingTime2 D 
                  ON D.accountID = F.accountID 
                     and D.deviceID = F.deviceID
    where 
       (from_unixtime(F.timestamp) between '2014-10-10 10:52:02' and '2014-10-30 10:52:02') 
       and F.accountID = 'vinhnghia' 
       and F.deviceID = '14C-00263' 
       and (D.reportType = '2' or D.reportType = '3') 
       and F.timestamp = D.stopTime 
    order by 
       F.timestamp asc
)
UNION
(
    SELECT distinct 
       from_unixtime(D.thoiGian) as col_1, 
       D.nhienLieu as col_2 
    FROM 
       gtse.tblDoXang D 
       inner join gtse.tblFuel F 
                  on D.accountID = F.accountID 
                     and D.deviceID = F.deviceID 
    where 
       D.accountID = 'vinhnghia' 
       and D.deviceID = '14C-00263' 
       and D.thoiGian <= F.timestamp 
    order by 
       D.thoiGian asc;
)
```

I hope I understood well and this could help.

Comment: your answer is excellent, I try and the query work correctly as I expected before. Thank you!

Comment: I'm really glad it helped you :) Best regards.